# How to get Blender's temp directory via the Python API?

Tags: python

How do I get blenders temp folder via python (bpy).

I want to store temporary cache files while running Blender and when closing Blender I want them to be removed on exit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Python's `tempfile` module.

First of all, Python has its own [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module, which is quite comprehensive and can likely do what you need
*(handles creating, temp files, directories and optionally - cleaning up when you're done)*.

### Blender's User Preference

If you want to access the temp user preference, you can do so via.
`bpy.context.user_preferences.filepaths.temporary_directory`
... which is initialized based on environment variables (See [Environment Variables](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line.html#environment-variables) in the manual).

### Blender's *'session'* Temp Directory

However Blender crease a sub-directory *within* the temp directory, for each session, which is cleared on exit *(even in the case of a crash)*.

And this is accessed via [`bpy.app.tempdir`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.html#bpy.app.tempdir), in the case you describe, this sounds like it may be a good option.

---

Note that it may work well to use the `tempfile` module, even if you access Blender's temp directory using Blender's API.